# Eclipse NullPointerException when dragging tab to a new location with custom perspectives

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I made an IPartListener so when I change between different file types I can change perspective automatically. But when I drag an editor tab to a new location, it iterates over the other tabs it crossed. Now I think because of this, the editors getting activated and eclipse wants to change perspectives too fast. And I get a new tab added named: Drag Placerholder which is an ErrorViewPart.
My code:

```
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
        IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        workbenchWindow.getPartService().addPartListener(new IPartListener() {                
            @Override
            public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                if (part instanceof MyEditor && MyEditor.isAutomaticPerspectiveChangeEnabled()) {
                    MyEditor editor = (MyEditor) part;
                    try {
                        editor.changePerspective();
                    } catch (WorkbenchException e) {
                        ErrorHandler.handleUnexpectedError(e);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
 }
```

I attached some pics, if I drag file1.abc after file3.xyz and the files between would use other perspective, I end up with a 4th tab and a NullPointerException
[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

I'm not sure why Eclipse is activating the tabs between the drag points, can I somehow block that?

Stacktrace:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DragAgent.dragFinished(DragAgent.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.PartDragAgent.dragFinished(PartDragAgent.java:93)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.finishDrag(DnDManager.java:285)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.startDrag(DnDManager.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager$1.dragDetected(DnDManager.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```